# Issue while integrating hibernate orm to spring boot application:Unable to create requested service[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Trying to resolve this issue

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

This occured when i've updated hibernate-core version to 5.6.4

**Datasource configuration**

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mypage
        username: postgres
        password: root
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        hikari:
            connection-timeout: 30000
            idle-timeout: 60000
            max-lifetime: 1800000
    jpa:
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
        properties:
            hibernate:
                temp:
                    use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false #to disable contextual lob creation when application starts.
    liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

**Please refer to the below stacktrace for more details**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at com.mypage.Application.main(Application.java:9) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue, in the stacktrace you will be seeing Access to `DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`. This needs to be set in the application property file where you've been defined all the datasource configuration values.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mypage
        username: postgres
        password: root
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        hikari:
            connection-timeout: 30000
            idle-timeout: 60000
            max-lifetime: 1800000
    jpa:
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
        properties:
            hibernate:
                temp:
                    use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false #to disable contextual lob creation when application starts.
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

`spring.jpa.databse-platform` property.

This was not required for the older version of hibernate-core, as I was able to run the application without setting this property. This I've only noticed when I updated hibernate-core version

**PS: Correct me if I'm wrong**